# Showing a property of the frobenius norm

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

If we let $E=u^* v$ which an outer product. Then is the frobenius norm of E

$||E||_F=||U||_F||V||_F$

How would I show this is true.

The frobenius norm is $E=(\sum_{i=1}^{m} \sum_{j=1}|e_{ij}^2|)^{1/2}$

But I am not sure how to proceed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have

$$ \| E \|_F^2 = \sum |u_i v_j|^2 = \left( \sum |u_i|^2 \right) \left( \sum |v_j|^2 \right) = \| U \|_{F}^2 \| V \|_{F}^2. $$